# Is it possible to require app specific PIN authentication for Android Keystore

Tags: android, authentication

I'm trying to implement local PIN authentication securely. As per OWASP MSTG (https://mobile-security.gitbook.io/mobile-security-testing-guide/android-testing-guide/0x05f-testing-local-authentication), there are 2 ways of doing this.

1. Use Confirm Credentials for use to authenticate using device lockscreen credentials (PIN/password/pattern)
2. Use Biometric authentication

Biometric is fine. However, confirm credentials seems to be tied to the device credentials. Is there any way of unlocking the Android Keystore using application specific credentials instead?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  The keystore itself isn't available to any apps but the system, the phrase "unlocking the keystore" doesn't parse.

Comment: I'm trying to implement local PIN authentication in my app. I'd like to integrate a cryptographic primitive within the Android Keystore with this, i.e. user enters an app specific PIN, which unlocks access to the Android Keystore, which does some cryptographic primitive, which the app then computes to determine if authentication is successful. This would deter runtime tampering attacks such as Frida from simply intercepting the Keystore call and bypassing it without user intervention.